# Cognos Report Author 10.2.1 and Drill-thru parameters

Tags: cognos-bi

I have a unique issue that I need to deal with. I have **Multiple Drill-Thru running from Source to Target Report**. So, Report A has multiple Drill-Thurs
from each Intersection to different Drill-Thru Reports. It was a little tricky 
but I got it working.

So, now, I have to use a item value or parameter to send from the Source to the **SAME EXACT Target Report** but for **different filters** that the Target Report can use to show different information.

So, *Source A ---> Target A*, based on parameter or Value of "Jaguars" and the Target will return only "Jaguars" information.

If **Source A ---> Target A**, based on parameter or Value of "BMW" and the Target will return only "BMW" information.

Since there is **no parameter in the Prompt Page** for the **Car Type**, I have to some how setup a value as "Jaguar" and send it as a value to the Target report. Same thing for the "BMW".

So, does anybody knows how I can setup a value in the Source and send it as a part of the Drill-Thru definition to the Target Report.

Thx so much for your time.

Comment: So, are you saying that there is no 'Car Type' data item as either a column header or row header? I'm assuming you are using a crosstab.

Comment: In the Source Report, I do have the Car Type that I can include in my main Query. The same Car Type is used as a filter within the Target Report. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I had to drop the Data Item that I needed to pass as Value as a part of the Crosstab. It's working now.

Comment: Try selecting one of the edges, either column or row, and select the 'Car Type' data item in the 'Properties' property.